# Eclipse Debug View suspend/resume shortcuts

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Eclipse version: 4.4.0

I want to suspend JVM with "space" and resume with "r" only when in Debug View.
In Preferences->General->Keys there is no option 
When: In Debug View. 
Can I add it? Do you know workaround?

Comment: There are `Debugging` and `Debugging Java` in *When*.

Comment: When I use Debugging it works in every window during debugging. I do not want that. I want simple shortcut in Debug View to quickly understand what 10-20 threads are doing.

Comment: Anyone found a solution to this? I really need this for the same reason as @pusheax